# Kotlin extension properties not recognized in V1.0.1

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

Revisiting some code from a pre-1.0.1 version of Kotlin, it appears that my extension property no longer works. In fact, it still does but I can no longer override it.

Consider this class:

```
class TestClass {

    override val loggerName: String
        get() = "A new name"

    fun aMethod() {
        info("test info message")
    }
}
```

Pre Kotlin 1.0.1 this would work if you have the following extensions:

```
val Any.loggerName: String
    get() = javaClass.simpleName!!

fun Any.info(message: String) {
    //...
}
```

loggerName would by default take the class name of the instance in question. Currently, loggerName is correctly assigned to **TestClass** in this case, however I cannot override it.

Is this an accidental bug or a new limitation in this new version of Kotlin? I have searched [Kotlin - Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-properties) but found only that it should work.

**Technicals**:

I am testing this in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1 with Kotlin plugin version 1.0.1-release-IJ143-32.

**EDIT 1:**

TestClass does not even recognize this property however when accessing an instance of TestClass (example: `instanceOfTestClass.loggerName`) it is recognized.

Comment: Do you have the imports in place?

Comment: Which version of studio your are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overriding an extension property with a property of a class was not possible in any pre-release version of Kotlin, nor it is possible in 1.0.1. Extension properties are compiled to static methods, and code accessing the extension properties is simply calling the static method; there is no possibility to perform dynamic dispatch based on the type of the receiver.

Without the override, the extension property will work. You need to make sure that you have imported it in the place where you try to access it.

Comment: Alright thanks, I suppose whatever I did was by accident then. It worked for one class but perhaps it wouldn't have if I tested it with more classes. Can it be solved by using an extension function instead or will that be the same outcome?

Comment: No, the outcome will be the same. The dispatch is always static.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `gradle` look like below :

```
 apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
...
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}
...
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
...
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.0-XYZ'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Replace `$kotlin_version` with your kotlin version.

**Note:** If you are using **Android Studio 2.0 Preview**, expect some **weir** behaviours in the Plugin, also in some situations it **stop** working, so for now suggest you to use **1.5** version as it’s working as expected.

See [Configuring Android Studio with Kotlin](https://medium.com/@juanchosaravia/learn-kotlin-while-developing-an-android-app-part-1-e0f51fc1a8b3#.1ojc8dhjw)

hope its helps you.